# fluentd filter regex pattern gives an invalid strptime format error

Tags: regex, fluentd

I am trying to use the regex filter to parse my log
My regex expression and sample string are as follows
Regex:

```
/^(?<logtime>[^\|]*)\S +(?<cpu-usr>\S+) +(?<cpu-sys>\S+) +(?<cpu-idl>\S+) +(?<cpu-wai>\S+) +(?<cpu-hiq>\S+) +(?<cpu-siq>[^|]+)\S +(?<mem-used>\S+) +(?<mem-buff>\S+) +(?<mem-cach>\S+) +(?<mem-free>\S+)/
```

Sample string:

```
07-07 17:18:12|  0   0 100   0   0   0| 197M 48.9M  182M  546M
```

So I have written the following filter into my fluent.conf file

```
#filter dstat log into fields. 
#----system---- ----total-cpu-usage---- ------memory-usage-----
#  date/time   |usr sys idl wai hiq siq| used  buff  cach  free
<filter input.dstat>
  @type parser
  format /^(?<logtime>[^\|]*)\S +(?<cpu-usr>\S+) +(?<cpu-sys>\S+) +(?<cpu-idl>\S+) +(?<cpu-wai>\S+) +(?<cpu-hiq>\S+) +(?<cpu-siq>[^|]+)\S +(?<mem-used>\S+) +(?<mem-buff>\S+) +(?<mem-cach>\S+) +(?<mem-free>\S+)/
  time_format %d-%m %H:%M:%S
  time_key logtime
  keep_time_key true
  key_name log
</filter>
```

However, I get the following error for this filter.

> fluentd_1        | 2017-07-07 05:42:36 +0000 [warn]: invalid time format: value = 07-0, error_class = ArgumentError, error = invalid strptime format - `%d-%m %H:%M:%S'

I have already checked the regex and time format using http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/ and it seems to be ok according to that. How do I proceed with this? My current assumption is that the error is due to %Y or year being missing from the time format. However my log does not contain the year information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used '-' in the names instead of '_'
After replacing them, it works fine.